# Is a Mold Host always in the ventilation of the Research Section's Protective Studies when entered before the Duck is Cleansed?

Tags: control

Is a Mold Host always in the ventilation of the Research Section's Protective Studies when entered before the Duck is Cleansed? Even without quitting and reloading?

I went in there twice before I caught the rubber duck. I wanted to farm Corrupted Samples.

Well, it's not one of the Underhill's escapees that bugged out. It respawned and I splatted it and it didn't count for that. And also because I splatted the right 3.